# Undefined symbols for architecture arm64, Xcode 12.3

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I have errors when trying to run tests. I read that the error may be related to unrelated files, but I did not find this problem in my project.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem and how did you solve it?

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "protocol descriptor for InTravel.URLRequestFactory", referenced from:
      l_got.$s8InTravel17URLRequestFactoryMp in Tests_RequestFactory.o
  "(extension in InTravel):InTravel.EndPointType.url.getter : Foundation.URL", referenced from:
      Tests_iOS.MockRequestFactory.createRequest(InTravel.EndPointType) throws -> Foundation.URLRequest in Tests_RequestFactory.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

[image]

Comment: Please post the code as code snippet rather than an image

Answer (score 2):

> Has anyone encountered a similar problem and how did you solve it?

Check the target membership for your various files. Make sure that the file in which those symbols are defined is included in the target you're trying to build.

Comment: Turned out to be I had a framework that wasn't included for my target. But I can't get my head around why the linker did not throw an error when linking for arm, only for arm64.